# Agregar una fila en la primera posición de un DataTable

Tags: c#, windows-forms, dataset

Trabajo con VS 2019, Windows Forms

Tengo los siguientes datos en un DataTable

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Quiero agregar una nueva fila en la cual mostrare un encabezado como A, B, C

Lo que espero es lo siguiente

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Lo he intentado de la siguiente manera

```
var dt = ds.Tables[0];
        dt.Rows.Add("A", "B", "C");
            
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dtHeader.NewRow(), 0);
```

Pero lo que intento agregar me sale en la ultima fila.

Comment: usas algún criterio de ordenamiento? puede que eso lo esté enviando al fondo. El código que tienes debe funcionar apropiadamente

Comment: dtHeader.Rows.Add("A", "B", "C"); esto lo agrego al final... dtHeader.Rows.InsertAt(dtHeader.NewRow(), 0);
 esto agrego algo vacia, en la posicion 0... no creo que es lo que vos queres..

Comment: No tengo algún criterio de ordenamiento solo cargo los datos desde la db

Comment: Así es me agrega una posicion vacia en la posición 0 claro eso no quiero, quiero que agregue los datos A,B,C en la primera posicion 0

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionarlo

```
DataRow row= dt.NewRow();
row[0] = "";
row[1] = "";
dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
```

Comment: Explicalo, por si a otros les hace falta